# How do you make some number of columns the same height while preserving wrapping in bootstrap.js?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

As an example I have a 3-column layout such as:
[image]

and would like to make the middle column the same height as whichever of the other two is the largest (the full row height.)  I also want it to be able to wrap when it gets too small, because it handles that part perfectly right now as:
[image]

[Here is a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/lecoder/opxr7pow/) that will allow you to resize and see the issue in action.

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
<h2 class="panel-heading">Example</h2>
<div class="container-fluid row vertical-align code-bg" style="padding: 0px;">
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-5 col-lg-5"><code><a class="keyword" href="#functions__return_type">function</a> <a class="name" href="#functions__function_name">foo</a>(<a class="name" href="#functions__argument_name">data</a>) {
    <span class="type">return</span> (<span class="name">data</span> != undefined ? <a class="name" href="#functions__return_value">data</a> : <a class="string" href="#functions__return_value">'no data'</a>);
}</code></div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-2 col-lg-1 text-center" style="background-color: #3B3B3B;">equivalent to</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-5 col-lg-6"><code><a class="flag" href="#functions__security">insecure</a> <a class="flag" href="#functions__access">public</a> <a class="flag" href="#functions__affinity">local</a> <a class="flag" href="#functions__extent">dynamic</a> <a class="flag" href="#functions__synchronization">sync</a> <a class="type" href="#functions__return_type">string</a> <a class="name" href="#functions__function_name">foo</a>(<a class="flag" href="#functions__argument_optionality">optional</a> <a class="type" href="#functions__argument_type">string</a> <a class="name" href="#functions__argument_name">data</a> = <a class="string" href="#functions__argument_default_value">'no data'</a>) {
    <span class="type">return</span> (<a class="name" href="#functions__return_value">data</a>);
}</code></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I see that you already started on using flexbox!
I've expanded on this in the fiddle below:

https://jsfiddle.net/opxr7pow/16/

So each of the column divs are also `display: flex;` and moved the `align-items: center;` style onto these rather than the row (it was preventing the columns from going full height).
Had to then use `justify-content: center;` to center align the middle column, as `text-align: center;` wasn't working. I'm not sure why this was though :(

Please use the JSFiddle above, as the code snippet looks a bit messy..

```css
body {
  background-color: #181818;
  color: #A9B7C6;
  font-family: "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
  border: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
code {
  background-color: #2B2B2B;
  color: #A9B7C6;
  display: block;
  font-family: "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 20px;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}
code:after {
  content: " ";
}
.code-bg {
  background-color: #2B2B2B;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 32px;
  margin: 0px;
}
h1 > a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}
h2 {
  font-size: 24px;
  margin: 0px;
}
h2 > a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}
h3 {
  font-size: 20px;
  margin: 0px;
}
h3 > a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}
h4 {
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 0px;
}
h4 > a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}
.list > li {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}
p {
  margin: 0px;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}
.text-center {
  text-align:center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.vertical-align {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.vertical-align > div {
  align-items:center;
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://bootswatch.com/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://bootswatch.com/slate/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="panel panel-default">
<h2 class="panel-heading">Example</h2>
<div class="container-fluid row vertical-align code-bg" style="padding: 0px;">
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-5 col-lg-5"><code><a class="keyword" href="#functions__return_type">function</a> <a class="name" href="#functions__function_name">foo</a>(<a class="name" href="#functions__argument_name">data</a>) {
    <span class="type">return</span> (<span class="name">data</span> != undefined ? <a class="name" href="#functions__return_value">data</a> : <a class="string" href="#functions__return_value">'no data'</a>);
}</code></div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-2 col-lg-1 text-center" style="background-color: #3B3B3B;">equivalent to</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-5 col-lg-6"><code><a class="flag" href="#functions__security">insecure</a> <a class="flag" href="#functions__access">public</a> <a class="flag" href="#functions__affinity">local</a> <a class="flag" href="#functions__extent">dynamic</a> <a class="flag" href="#functions__synchronization">sync</a> <a class="type" href="#functions__return_type">string</a> <a class="name" href="#functions__function_name">foo</a>(<a class="flag" href="#functions__argument_optionality">optional</a> <a class="type" href="#functions__argument_type">string</a> <a class="name" href="#functions__argument_name">data</a> = <a class="string" href="#functions__argument_default_value">'no data'</a>) {
    <span class="type">return</span> (<a class="name" href="#functions__return_value">data</a>);
}</code></div>
</div>
</div>
```